# Can I call a function when server restarts or shutdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a in house app which is accessed from multiple clients.There are few xml files on the server which need to  be recreated every time whenever server starts.

My question is how can I check whether the server is shut-downed or restarted via my php program? which seems abit tricky..;-) so can i run a method on server shutdown?

I am using codeigniter.

Thanks,

Comment: What HTTP server are you using ? you are going to need to interact with the HTTP server - PHP is only called on demand unless you create somekind of scheduled task

Comment: Indeed, what operating system does your server use, and what kind of webserver (apache, lighttp) do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file which takes care of creating xml files.
And place that batch file in windows start up folder. So that every time machine starts that batch file will be executed and xml files will be generated.
In batch file call your application which generates the xml files.

Answer (score 2):

On systems that support `cron(8)` (Linux, xBSD, etc), you can use `@reboot` feature to execute command after reboot. Syntax for `crontab` is simply:

```
@reboot  /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 0):

what system are you on, Linux?

i would use a script called over PHP Cli that is called when the system starts.

References:

on PHP Cli
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

on RC scripts - called when the system starts:
http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

you can find more if you just google for those.

also like the @reboot solution, that plaes proposed.
here some examples
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/